# How to calculate the average of the value of the previous row + the value of the current row + the value of the subsequent row in R?

Tags: r, excel, function, dplyr

I'm trying to get the values from a relatively simple averaging in R, but I'm having trouble finding the best solution.

To be clearer, I intend to create an additional column called TMA with mutate and inside it get the values of these averages for each row, as in the Excel image below:

[Excel easy way example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I16BO.png)

Comment: I´m sorry guys =MÉDIA() in portuguese language in my Excel is the same as =MEAN() or =AVG() ...

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of "rolling window" functions in various packages across R.
The following is based on `{slider}`. If the syntax is not your style, look at `{zoo}`  and its `rollmean()` function.

**reproducible dataset/sample**
You will find a lot of friends here, if you provide a reproducible data set.
I picked part of the data presented in your image. Think about doing this in the future.

I converted your month-year into a character of year-month(number). In R, I recommend you use proper Date or datetime objects for this. This can help with other transformations. ((But that is another discussion))

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
    Data = c("2021-03", "2021-04","2021-05","2021-06","2021-07","2021-08")
    ,ANOM = c(-0.79,-0.72,-0.46,-0.28,-0.38,-0.45)
)
```

**using {slider}**
To understand what slider does print out the following:

```
library(slider)

> df %>% slide(~.x, .before = 2)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Data     ANOM
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 2021-03 -0.79
1 2021-03 -0.79

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Data     ANOM
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 2021-03 -0.79
2 2021-04 -0.72

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Data     ANOM
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 2021-03 -0.79
2 2021-04 -0.72
3 2021-05 -0.46
```

This builds a "sliding window" of size 3, i.e. the actual value and the 2 previous.
Note that you may want to handle the partial windows differently. Check the documentation for it.

**rolling mean for previous, current, and next row**
Now let's use this for the desired sliding window along the `ANOM` variable of your dataframe. As we know the output are doubles we use the `slide_dbl()` function (otherwise you would get a list column).
The original question is about a rolling mean for the previous, current, and next row. Thus, we set the `.before` and `.after` appropriately in terms of steplength.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(TMA = slide_dbl(ANOM, mean, .before = 1, .after = 1))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Data     ANOM    TMA
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-03 -0.79 -0.755
2 2021-04 -0.72 -0.657
3 2021-05 -0.46 -0.487
4 2021-06 -0.28 -0.373
5 2021-07 -0.38 -0.37 
6 2021-08 -0.45 -0.415
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ray! It worked very well for me !!

Comment: If the solution worked well, you might want to vote it or any other answer a) as a helpful answer and/or b) as you accepted one so that others see if it was helpful in case tehy encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different and more verbose solution would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    Data = c("2021-03", "2021-04","2021-05","2021-06","2021-07","2021-08"),
    ANOM = c(-0.79,-0.72,-0.46,-0.28,-0.38,-0.45))

df %>%
  mutate(ANOM_lead = lead(ANOM),
         ANOM_lag  = lag(ANOM),
         ANOM_avg  = rowMeans(across(c(ANOM, ANOM_lead, ANOM_lag))))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Data     ANOM ANOM_lead ANOM_lag ANOM_avg
  <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2021-03 -0.79     -0.72    NA      NA    
2 2021-04 -0.72     -0.46    -0.79   -0.657
3 2021-05 -0.46     -0.28    -0.72   -0.487
4 2021-06 -0.28     -0.38    -0.46   -0.373
5 2021-07 -0.38     -0.45    -0.28   -0.37 
6 2021-08 -0.45     NA       -0.38   NA
```

Here, we first create the lead and lag variables for ANOM and then simply get the row mean. Whether you also want to calculate a mean for the first and teh last row is up to you, which you can control with the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to the `rowMeans` function. Of course, you can also omit the lead and lag variables afterwards if you want with a `select` command.